# Express POST request.body undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make POST work with Express (4.13.3 version). when I print request.body.user, it says 'undefined'. I am using Chrome Poster to post my JSON request. Here is how my request looks

```
{
"user":"testUser",
 "password":"test pwd"
}
```

the URL I use: http://localhost:4000/first

and my server.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/first', function (request, response) {
    console.log('FIRST POST hello world');
    console.log('req.body:' + request);
   var user_name=request.body.user;
  var password=request.body.password;
  console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
  response.end("yes");
}); 

var server = app.listen(4000, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

when I post the request, here is what I see on my Node console.

```
Example app listening at http://:::4000
FIRST POST hello world
req.body:[object Object]
User name = undefined, password is undefined
```

Why I am not able to get my 'user' and 'password' values here from my request? I am getting 'undefined' for both of these variables.

Comment: You need to set the `Content-Type` of the request.

Comment: I have that set 'Content-Type:application/json' in my Poster options in Header's section. Name: Content-Type, value: application/json.

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: I got "req.body:[object Object]" when I did "console.log('req.body:' + request.body);"  in app.post('/first', function (request, response) method.

Comment: You need to pass `req.body` directly to `console.log()` (without string concatenation) so it can enumerate properties.

Comment: I tried what you said and it printed '{}'.

Comment: Ok. It worked now. All I have to do was to get a Poster plugin for Mozilla Firefox. I am not sure what is wrong with Chrome Poster. This is the only change I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

if this still doesn't work change your request to this:

```
user=testUser&password=test+pwd
```

This is how the request body have to look using Chrome's "Advanced REST Client".

Comment: Saved my day. I was writing the requests before using bodyParser().